# Temporary string comparison with > and < operators in C++

Tags: c++, string, operators, temporary, chararray

These operators do not perform lexicographical comparisons and seem to provide inconsistent results.

```
#include <iostream>
int main () {
    std::cout << ("70" < "60") << '\n';
    std::cout << ("60" < "70") << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

and

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << ("60" < "70") << '\n';
    std::cout << ("70" < "60") << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

both print

```
1
0
```

The same holds true for `std::less<>()`. However, `std::less<std::string>()` provides the correct lexicographical comparison. What is the reason for this behaviour?
Are the comparisons shown above comparing the addresses of char arrays?

Comment: "*comparing the addresses of char arrays*" That's what a string literal is (more or less).

Comment: Because string literals are character pointers and this compares random memory addresses.

Comment: *These operators do not perform lexicographical comparisons* - Why should they?

Comment: Good thing is that comparision between two arrays is deprecated in C++20, so you should see a warning in a modern C++ compiler. Reading warnings is a good habit.

Comment: For lexicographical comparison of C-style strings use [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp).

Comment: @marcinj do you have a source for that?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ced6191ff426517. and https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1120r0.html

Comment: Incidentally, those are not "temporary string"s, as the title says. They are **string literals**; nothing temporary about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Character literals are character arrays. You are comparing these arrays, which after array-to-pointer decay means you are comparing the addresses of the first byte of these arrays.

Each character literal may refer to a different such array, even if it has the same value. And there is no guarantee about the order of their addresses.

So any possible outcome for your tests is allowed. `0`/`0` as well as `0`/`1`, `1`/`0` and `1`/`1`.

---

You can avoid all the C-style array behavior of string literals by always using `std::string` or `std::string_view` literals instead:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::string_literals;

int main () {
    std::cout << ("70"s < "60"s) << '\n';
    std::cout << ("60"s < "70"s) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

This uses the user-defined string literal `operator""s` from the standard library to immediately form `std::string`s from the string literals. `sv` can be used for `std::string_view`s instead. (`string_view` will incur less performance cost, in particular no dynamic allocation.)